# How can I setup Adobe Premiere with Git?

Tags: git, adobe-premiere

I am using Adobe Premiere Pro 2018 for video editing. I want to set it up with git so that I have version control of the project file.

The project file (.prproj) is a gzip of an XML.

Is it possible to configure git to compare the XMLs inside the project file when I do git diff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a "textconv" filter, which will be used by git to convert files into a diff-able format when displaying. See:

- https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv
- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

In short, you first need to define the filter via git config (always untracked):

```
git config --global diff.gzipped.textconv "gunzip -c"

[diff "gzipped"]
    textconv = gunzip -c
```

Then assign it to .prproj files via .gitattributes (tracked) or .git/info/attributes (untracked):

```
*.prproj diff textconv=gzipped
```

(The `diff` attribute is needed to enable diffing altogether, i.e. tell git that this file should be treated as text and not binary.)

You can also use this method to make more advanced converters, e.g. additionally canonicalize and prettify the XML (if the program writes everything as a single long line).

---

However, textconv filters are display-only. Storing a compressed file in Git still has the disadvantage that there is no similarity between versions, so if the file is also large, it'll cause the repository to grow accordingly with each version. (Compare this to text files, which are usually very similar between versions, therefore even a long commit history can be very efficiently delta-compressed.)

You might instead want to use "smudge/clean" filters, which work in a similar way but their results are permanent – that is, git stores a 'cleaned' version internally, and transforms it back (smudges) on checkout. The config would look like:

```
[filter "gzipped"]
    clean = gunzip -c
    smudge = gzip -c
```

And the attributes file would look like:

```
*.prproj filter=gzipped
```

This lets you take advantage of Git's delta compression, although also has the disadvantage that every clone must have the filter configured in their git config (it can't be automatically distributed). If someone clones the repo without having the filters yet, they will need to `git checkout --renormalize`.

Again, you can expand the 'clean' filter to also prettify the XML (xml_pp) and make it diff in a visually nicer way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. By the way only the second method worked. With the first one, git diff was still saying that the file is binary.

Comment: Ah, yes, you also need a `diff` attribute to mark the type as text and enable diffing.